# How to change Terraria player number

Tags: terraria

Is there a program to change the number given to a player by terraria? i made a new character on a separate computer, so its internal data is player 1. when i copied the .plr file onto the computer with my old characters, the original player 1 shows up in the character selection, but not the new player 1, even though i changed the file name to the next available number. However, when i moved the other player files out and named the new player player 1 again, it does show up in the character select screen. is there a limit to the number of characters that shows in the character select screen? the inventory/character editors i found dont have any "number" changers

Comment: Why not just pick the character with the most health/mana, dump the other's items in a chest, then retrieve them?

Comment: @kotekzot - Because sometimes you want to keep your powerful character around, and also have another low level one to work on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no character number. Terraria just loads all `.plr` files in its player save directory, in no particular order.

If you copied over a player file and the character isn't showing up, then it's either corrupted or you didn't do it right. Also, there is a hardcoded **limit of 5 characters**, so if you're already at that limit, there's your problem.

Comment: Also, I should probably clarify that "no particular order" means that the [function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/vstudio/wz42302f?cs-lang=csharp) Terraria uses has no defined order. In practice, it's probably alphabetical or something.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a second character; doesn't matter what. Then, you need to rename the .plr number to that new character's number. After that, you need to remove the newly-made character and put the character you changed the number on into the player's folder and it should work.

Comment: This answer really didn't add any new information.  This just changes the order of the characters.  The problem was likely the author had 5 characters already which is a hardcoded limit.